# Add Range from one list to another

Tags: vb.net, list, addrange

I have a `list(of string)` and I search it to get a start and end range, I then need to add that range to a separate list

ex: List A = "a" "ab" "abc" "ba" "bac" "bdb" "cba" "zba"

I need List B to be all the b's (3-5)

What I want to do is `ListB.Addrange(ListA(3-5))`
How can I accomplish this??

Comment: The search keys are : `.FindAll` and `.CopyTo`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `List.GetRange()`

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Sub Main()
    '                                               0    1     2      3     4      5      6      7
    Dim ListA As New List(Of String)(New String() {"a", "ab", "abc", "ba", "bac", "bdb", "cba", "zba"})
    Dim ListB As New List(Of String)

    ListB.AddRange(ListA.GetRange(3, 3))
    For Each Str As String In ListB
        Console.WriteLine(Str)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

or you can use Linq

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        '                                               0    1     2      3     4      5      6      7
        Dim ListA As New List(Of String)(New String() {"a", "ab", "abc", "ba", "bac", "bdb", "cba", "zba"})
        Dim ListB As New List(Of String)

        ListB.AddRange(ListA.Where(Function(s) s.StartsWith("b")))
        ' This does the same thing as .Where()
        ' ListB.AddRange(ListA.FindAll(Function(s) s.StartsWith("b")))
        For Each Str As String In ListB
            Console.WriteLine(Str)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

[image]